# SQL - how to get all rows in parent based on number of children of that parent?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have 2 tables:

- parent table: id, name
- child table: id, name, id_parent

Now, I want to list rows in parent table have the number rows of children is 3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's difficult to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions

Comment: It is Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done in several ways. Easiest is perhaps a correlated sub-query in the `WHERE` clause to count the number of children:

```
select *
from parents p
where (select count(*) from children c
       where c.id_parent = p.id) = 3
```

Or a `GROUP BY`, with `HAVING`:

```
select p.*
from parents p
join children c
     on c.id_parent = p.id
group by p.id
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: Oh, this is the great solution. Thanks jarlh. Btw, if i want to get the number of children with that result, how i can edit query ?

Answer (score 0):

I edit my query like this.

```
select p.*, count(c.id)
from parents p
join children c
     on c.id_parent = p.id
group by p.id
having count(*) = 3
```

is it ok ? jarlh

Comment: Looks just fine!

Comment: I found a missed in return data. If i use count(*)=0, it return empty.

Comment: If you want to include parents without children, switch to `LEFT JOIN`. And do `having count(c.id) = 0`.